# get next value in list Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list of unique dates in chronological order.
I have a dataframe with dates in it. I want to use the list of dates in the dataframe to get the NEXT date in the list (find the date in dataframe in the list, return the date to the right of it ( next chronological date).

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a datatable of 40000 dates. I got a unique list of the dates and I sorted them. Now what I want to do is for date (t), append date(t+1) to the dataframe. I don't want to write a for-loop since I have 40000 dates

Answer (score 0):

so for every item in the dataframe there is an exact match for its date in the list of unique dates and you want to move it to the next date

you should use a dictionary for this really

```
next_date_dictionary = dict(zip(sequential_list_of_dates,sequential_list_of_dates[1:]))
```

then you simply look up the next date in the dictionary

```
next_date = next_date_dictionary.get(row.date)
```

alternatively if you want to replace the date column you can use `replace`

```
data_frame.replace({"date":next_date_dictionary})
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that printing the list wouldn't work, and you haven't provided us with any code to work with, or an example print of what your date time looks like. My best suggestion is to use the sort function.

dataframe.sort()

If I wanted a specific date to print, I would have to say to print it by index number once you have it sorted. Without knowing what your computers ability is to handle print statements of this size, I suggest copying this sorted file to a out txt file to ensure that you are getting the proper response.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is one way of doing this:

```
In [210]:
# generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2014,3,2), end=dt.datetime(2014,4,23))})
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 53 entries, 0 to 52
Data columns (total 1 columns):
dates    53 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 848.0 bytes
```

Now I'd create a df from your date list:

```
In [219]:

base = dt.datetime(2014,5,3)
date_list = [base - dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 70)]
date_df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':date_list})
date_df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 70 entries, 0 to 69
Data columns (total 1 columns):
dates    70 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 1.1 KB
```

Then add a new column to this `date_df` that [`shifts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) the `dates` column by 1 and then set the index to be the `dates`:

```
In [220]:

date_df['date_lookup'] = date_df['dates'].shift(1)
date_df = date_df.set_index('dates')
date_df.head()
Out[220]:
           date_lookup
dates                 
2014-05-03         NaT
2014-05-02  2014-05-03
2014-05-01  2014-05-02
2014-04-30  2014-05-01
2014-04-29  2014-04-30
```

Then call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) on the orig df and pass the `date_df` and access the `date_lookup` column, `map` will use the index to perform a lookup which will return the corresponding next value:

```
In [221]:

df['date_next'] = df['dates'].map(date_df['date_lookup'])
df.head()
Out[221]:
       dates  date_next
0 2014-03-02 2014-03-03
1 2014-03-03 2014-03-04
2 2014-03-04 2014-03-05
3 2014-03-05 2014-03-06
4 2014-03-06 2014-03-07
```